# Updating a nested array in a collection with it's index

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm new to MeteorJs and I'm loving it. But I'm , i am working on a meteorJs app that has to to with opinions (yes or no) and votes on them. The structure is such that the Question (main post) is parent to the comments and comments is parents likes i.e. question(object) > yes or no(array) > likes(array)
So, i have this collection structure for the post (question in this case)

```
{
    "_id" : "s2QBCnv6fXv5YbjAP",
    "question" : "Is this real change?",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-05-13T21:05:23.381Z"),
    "yes" : [
            {
                    "heading" : "Yes It is",
                    "body" : "I think this government knows what they are doing. That's why there has not been any form of protest",
                    "email" : "I think this government knows what they are doing. That's why there has not been any form of protest",
                    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-05-13T21:08:25.119Z"),
                    "replies" : [ ],
                    "likes" : [
                            "sdfsd6sd556shsdbdjs88s",
                            "sdfsd6sd556shsdbdjkhj88s",
                            "the_use_id",
                            "the_use_id",
                            "the_use_id"
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "heading" : "Well, Yes",
                    "body" : "I think this is change as we all want to know what the government is doing and I am grateful to be alive at this time",
                    "email" : "I think this is change as we all want to know what the government is doing and I am grateful to be alive at this time",
                    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-05-13T21:10:47.123Z"),
                    "replies" : [ ],
                    "likes" : [ ]
            }
    ],
    "no" : [
            {
                    "heading" : "Not at All",
                    "body" : "This is not the change I wanted. This is waste of four years and I amm waiting to see the promised change",
                    "email" : "kenshin@kay.com",
                    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-05-13T21:12:58.977Z"),
                    "replies" : [ ],
                    "likes" : [ ]
            }
    ],
    "author" : "admin",
    "image" : "/cfs/files/QuestionImages/DzdpK6NdurZMTwAse"
```

}

What i want is this: Write a helper to push the loggedIn user's ID into the likes array when the like button is clicked I wrote this helper

```
 "click #like_yes_comment": function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var questionId = Template.parentData(1)._id;
    Questions.update(
        {_id: questionId, , 'yes.heading':this.heading}, 
        {$push: {'yes.0.likes': "the_use_id"}}
    );        

}
```

but i got this error

```
Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]
```

then I re-edited it to look like this

```
"click #like_yes_comment": function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var questionId = Template.parentData(1)._id;
    Questions.update(
        {_id: questionId}, 
        {$push: {'yes.0.likes': "the_use_id"}}
    );        

}
```

Then it works but it only updates the first "like" array.

So, here's my question. How can I update each like in the Questions>yes/no>likes array. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You should generate extra id in Your **yes** array

```
"yes" : [
         {
           id : Random.id(),
           heading : "..."
           ...
```

and then use **the positional $ operator**, so:

```
Questions.update(
    {_id: questionId, "yes.id": yesId}, 
    {$push: {'yes.$.likes': userId}}
);
```

Comment: She's already using `heading` as an id. @kenshinman - using the $ instead of 0 might help you however.

Comment: This almost works but it shows this error in the console **allow-deny.js:483 Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]** how can i resolve this using Meteor.method

Comment: You need to use the document's _id, so:

`var docid = Questions.findOne({_id: questionId);
Questions.update(
    {_id: docid._id, "yes.id": yesId}, 
    {$push: {'yes.$.likes': userId}}
);`

Comment: Thanks. i it worked on the server side. this code did it `likeYes: function(yes, questionId, userId){
        Questions.update(
            {_id: questionId, "yes.id": yes.id}, 
            {$push: {'yes.$.likes': userId}}
        );
    }`

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :)